# fetch all infusionsoft tags via api

Tags: api, tags, infusionsoft

I am writing an application and in one of my forms, I want to put in a listbox populated with all available tags from my client's InfusionSoft account. I am new to the InfusionSoft API and would greatly appreciate it if someone can point me toward the right direction.

Thanks

Comment: @DeshDeep, Nothing yet actually, right now I hardcoded the tag ID into the form and then tag contacts via the api

Answer (score 1):

To get a list of all available tags, you'll want to [query](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/xml-rpc/#data-query-a-data-table) the [ContactGroup](https://developer.infusionsoft.com/docs/table-schema/) table. That will return back a list of all available tags!

For example, if you were using the PHP iSDK, you could get the first 1,000 tags this way:

```
$app = new iSDK();
// perform authorization tasks

$returnFields = array('Id','GroupDescription', 'GroupName');
$query = array('GroupName' => '%');
$tags = $app->dsQuery("ContactGroup",1000,0,$query,$returnFields);
```

Comment: @sMATTerings, was this helpful?

Comment: is there a way to use `NOT` in my queries? e.g. `'Id' => '!111'`?

Comment: Not Equal to ex: Id => '~<>~123'